# Get value of dynamic objects in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to read a value from HTTP response. Here is an example of the response in which I'm trying to fetch (description) value:

```
{
  "result":{
    "code":"200.300.404",
    "description":"successful"
  },
  "buildNumber":"1f9@2021-12-23 09:56:49 +0000",
  "timestamp":"2021-12-25 17:22:35+0000",
  "ndc":"8976eaedf8da"
}
```

Here is my code

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> responseData;

string data = "entityId=8a8294174d0595bb014d05d82e5b01d2";

string url = "https://test.oppwa.com/v1/checkouts/" + CheckoutId + "/payment?" + data;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer xxxx";

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // var s = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
}

// If responseDate.Description=success then enroll user and register the payment
         
var res = responseData["result"];
            
// I'm trying to do this but not working 
var res = responseData["result"]["description"];

return responseData;
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: use `HttpClient` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JToken` or `JObject` of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`.

For example, if your response format like as below:

```
{
  "result":{
    "code":"200.300.404",
    "description":"successful"
  },
  "buildNumber":"1f9@2021-12-23 09:56:49 +0000",
  "timestamp":"2021-12-25 17:22:35+0000",
  "ndc":"8976eaedf8da"
}
```

You can use below code for this purpose:

```
...

string webResponseAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();

dynamic dynamicResult = JToken.Parse(webResponseAsString);

string description = dynamicResult.result.description
```

For more details, you can visit this links:

[Using JSON.NET for dynamic JSON parsing](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing)

[Querying JSON with dynamic](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)

[What is better to use when parsing dynamic JSON data: JToken or c# built in dynamic type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42483568/8810311)

Comment: Thank you so much. the issue resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
...

var jsonObject=JObject.Parse(json);
var result=jsonObject["result"];

var description = jsonObject["result"]["description"];

// or 
var description =result["description"];
```

description value

```
successful
```

Answer (score 0):

```
responseData["result"].description
```

Will get you the JValue of "successful".

Although there are some other issues. Deserialize needs an instance of JsonSerializer, it is not a static method. Here is a full example without using a Dictionary.

```
var response = @"
{
  ""result"":{
    ""code"":""200.300.404"",
    ""description"":""successful""
  },
  ""buildNumber"":""1f9@2021-12-23 09:56:49 +0000"",
  ""timestamp"":""2021-12-25 17:22:35+0000"",
  ""ndc"":""8976eaedf8da""
}
";

var responseData = new JsonSerializer()
    .Deserialize<dynamic>(
        new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(response)));
responseData.result.description; //successful
```